# Display alert message and redirect the page

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I have the following code. On failure i need to get the alert **Already exists** and redirect to te registration page. But on success i need to check the session and based on the role id i need to redirect the page but the alert and redirection is not happening in this case ... can you please tell where i am wrong

```
if ($referral_patient_id != NULL) {
    echo "<script language='javascript'>
    alert('Successfully Added');
    if ($_SESSION['role_id'] != 6) {
        echo 'window.location.href="../Laboratory_Home"';
    } else {
        echo 'window.location.href="../Billing_Home"';
    } </script>";
} else {
    echo "<script language='javascript'>
    alert('Already Exists');
    window.location.href = '../../LabAdd_Patients'; 
    </script>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php if ($referral_patient_id != NULL) { ?>
    <script type='javascript'>
    alert('Successfully Added');
<?php  if ($_SESSION['role_id'] != 6) { ?>
     window.location.href="../Laboratory_Home";

<?php } else {  ?>
       window.location.href="../Billing_Home";
<?php  }  ?>
</script>
  <?php  }else { ?>
      <script type='javascript'>
         alert('Already Exists');
        window.location.href = '../../LabAdd_Patients'; 
  </script>
   <?php } ?>
```

Try this one dude.

Answer (score 1):

You have mixed content. PHP and Javascript. Try this one

```
echo "<script language='javascript'>
        alert('Successfully Added');
     </script>";

if($_SESSION['role_id']!=6){
  echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location.href='../Laboratory_Home'</script>";
} else {
  echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location.href='../Billing_Home'</script>";
}
```

Or this one

```
echo "<script language='javascript'>
        alert('Successfully Added');
        if( ".$_SESSION['role_id']." !=6) {
            window.location.href='../Laboratory_Home';
        } else {
            window.location.href='../Billing_Home';
        }
    </script>";
```

Comment: i am getting error "Message: syntax error, unexpected '.' "

Answer (score 1):

Try this javascript code :

```
<script language='javascript'>
var referral_patient_id = '<?php echo $referral_patient_id; ?>';
if(referral_patient_id != null)
{
    alert('Successfully Added');
    var role_id = '<?php echo $_SESSION["role_id"]; ?>';
    if (role_id != '6') {
        window.location.href="../Laboratory_Home";
    } else {
        window.location.href="../Billing_Home";
    }
} 
else
{
    alert('Already Exists');
    window.location.href = '../../LabAdd_Patients'; 
}
</script>
```